# Filtering child processes

Tags: wfp

I have a callout driver at **FWPM_LAYER_ALE_FLOW_ESTABLISHED_V4** layer with the filter condition **FWPM_CONDITION_ALE_APP_ID** to filter traffic from a specific application.

However, with some applications, they also spawn some child processes and one of them may communicate with the Internet, so filtering the parent process will 
give no output, with the filtering condition FWPM_CONDITION_ALE_APP_ID, WFP 
filters the process created by this application only.

How can I filter the parent and all its child processes?

Comment: Made readable and simple.

Comment: Please add code for reproduction or what you have tried.